# Changing Color of Floating Action Button Flutter

Tags: flutter, background-color, floating-action-button

I want to change Color of my floating button when i hit that button but couldn't find out a way to do that, how can i solve it? thanks in advance.

```
 var color1;
    var floatingActionButton1 = FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          simpleInterest.principal = double.parse(_principalController.text);
          color1 = Colors.green;
        });
      },
      elevation: 40,
      backgroundColor: color1,
      heroTag: "btn1",
      child: Icon(Icons.check),
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go through the code:

```
var isPressed = false;
.....
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    child: Icon(Icons.check),
    backgroundColor: isPressed ? Colors.green : Colors.blue,
    onPressed: () => setState(() => isPressed = !isPressed),
  ),
```